# Is it possible to use Pandas Overlap in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Python 3.7,
Pandas 25

I have a Pandas Dataframe with columns for startdate and enddate.  I am looking for ranges that overlap the range of my variable(s).  Without being verbose and composing a series of greater than/less than statements with ands/ors to filter out the rows I need, I would like to use some sort of interval "overlap".  It appears Pandas has this functionality:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.overlaps.html

The following test works:

```
range1 = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'),closed='both')
range2 = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'),closed='both')
range1.overlaps(range2)
```

However, when I go to apply it to the dataframe columns it does not.  I am not sure if there is something wrong in my syntax, or if this simply can not be applied to a dataframe.  Here are some of the things I have tried (and received the gamut of errors):

```
start_range = '2017-07-01 00:00:00'
end_current = '2019-07-01 00:00:00'
reporttest_range = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp(start_range),pd.Timestamp(end_current),closed='both')
reporttest_filter = my_dataframe[my_dataframe['startdate']['enddate'].overlaps(reporttest_range)]
reporttest_filter = my_dataframe[my_dataframe['startdate','enddate'].overlaps(reporttest_range)]
reporttest_filter = my_dataframe[(my_dataframe['startdate','enddate']).overlaps(reporttest_range)]
reporttest_filter = my_dataframe.filter(['startdate','enddate']).overlaps(reporttest_range)
reporttest_filter = my_dataframe.filter['startdate','enddate'].overlaps(reporttest_range)
reporttest_filter = my_dataframe.filter(['startdate','enddate']).overlaps(reporttest_range)
print(reporttest_filter)
```

Can someone please point me to an efficient way to accomplish this?

As requested, the dataframe output looks like this:

```
      record    startdate    enddate
0         99    2017-07-01 2018-06-30
1        280    2018-08-01 2021-07-31
2        100    2017-07-01 2018-06-30
3        281    2017-07-01 2018-06-30
```

Comment: could you share a few rows of `my_dataframe` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create `IntervalIndex` from `df.startdate` and `df.enddate` and use `overlaps` against `reporttest_range`. Your sample returns all true, so I add row for `False` case.

```
Sample df:   

   record  startdate    enddate
0    9931 2017-07-01 2018-06-30
1   28075 2018-08-01 2021-07-31
2   10042 2017-07-01 2018-06-30
3   28108 2017-07-01 2018-06-30
4   28109 2016-07-01 2016-12-30
5   28111 2017-07-02 2018-09-30

iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.startdate, df.enddate, closed='both')
iix.overlaps(reporttest_range)

Out[400]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

Use it to pick only overlapping rows

```
df[iix.overlaps(reporttest_range)]

Out[401]:
   record  startdate    enddate
0    9931 2017-07-01 2018-06-30
1   28075 2018-08-01 2021-07-31
2   10042 2017-07-01 2018-06-30
3   28108 2017-07-01 2018-06-30
5   28111 2017-07-02 2018-09-30
```

Comment: Thank you - this appears to be exactly what I need.